# Como apagar todos arquivos de um branch e copiar de outro branch

Tags: git

Tenho um branch chamado `stage` e outro `dev`
o dev recebe todos os branchs temporários de features e fix porém nem todos eles são aprovados e vão para o stage.
O Problema é que o dev tem tantos commits q nunca foram aprovados, ou seja códigos que estão ali, mas não estão mais no stage.

**Como apago todos os arquivos do `dev` e faço um clone do stage para o `dev`?**
Ou seja, o dev será um clone do meu stage atual

Pensei que seria algo como `rebase`, porém ao ler ele me parece que é para mudar o histórico, não quero mudar o histórico, alias histórico do dev não me importa, quero apenas fazer o dev ser um clone do meu stage atual.

*OBS: todos os branch são sincronizado com um versionador web e distribuido para vários computadores.*

Comment: Por que você não apaga o branch e recria a partir do outro?

Comment: corrigindo...@bfavaretto Se eu apagar local eu não terei problema ao tentar fazer o push depois?

Comment: Mas pq apagar só o local? Apaga o remoto também.

Comment: e depois recria? as pessoas que tem ele local terão problema para fazer o pull?

Comment: Os outros precisariam fazer um novo pull. Tem outras formas, mas é mais complexo e não sei explicar